# Catching and Parsing AWS RDSDataService exceptions

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-rds-data-service

I am using [RDSDataService](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds-data.html) in a lambda to execute queries in an Aurora Serverless DB. It's all good when everything runs fine, but when there is an error running the query I get something like this

> An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the ExecuteStatement operation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_role_role_name_key"
> Detail: Key (role_name)=(Test3          ) already exists.

I am catching that using a generic except `Exception as e` and then printing `e`.

Questions:

1. What package do I need to import to catch BadRequestException
2. How would I parse it to extract the detail part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS confirmed that it is not possible to properly parse the details of a Data API exception when using Postgresql (see [this github issue](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/2300) for updates).

If using the MySQL version of Aurora, the `aurora-data-api` package effectively returns a better exception format, since the SQLSTATE code can be parsed. We can see in [this internal function](https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/aurora-data-api/blob/509cefe2645af0d9cc21449fb739a18b13410062/aurora_data_api/__init__.py#L205) the difference in parsing.

---

For now, the only way to parse the exceptions from a Postgresql Aurora DB with Data API is to use string comparison like this:

```py
if errorMessage.contains('a known substring of a specific exception message'):
   # Here we "know" the exception type
```